# Problem with a do-while loop and creating an alert

Tags: javascript, html, alert, do-while

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to make a program to continuosly click one button unless another button is present. (I'd also love to get an alert when the second button appears but I don't know how to do that.)

This is what I got:

```
Do {Let button=document.getElementById("find"); 
Let want= document.getElementById("bba"); 
setInterval(function(){ 
button.click();
}, 10000); } 
while (want.click=false)
```

I keep getting errors (unidentified syntex). I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `do` not `Do`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Same for `Let`

Comment: VM2985:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: want is not defined
    at <anonymous>:6:18
(anonymous) @ VM2985:6
event:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE
2VM2985:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:4:12
(anonymous) @ VM2985:4
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ VM2985:3

Comment: @S.Grun May I ask why you would want to achieve that?

Comment: It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve. This code makes a lot of interval timers not just one. And those timers won’t stop.

Comment: Sure :) I'm in school and I just took a big exam, I want to know exactly when my grade gets put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is use a single setInterval :

```
    window.setInterval(function() {
      if (!document.getElementById("button2")) {
 document.getElementById("button1").click();
    } else {
document.getElementById("button2").click();
alert("second button appeared");
    }
    }, 100);
```

Sorry for formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: When I run it it still says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change button1 to find and button2 to bba?

Comment: window.setInterval(function() {
      if (!document.getElementById("bba")) {
 document.getElementById("find").click();
    } else {
document.getElementById("bba").click();
alert("breathe!");
    }
    }, 100);

Comment: this is what I put in

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking over your code I see two main errors. The first is that you used a capital do and let, JavaScript is case sensitive so you need to use lowercase. The second is that in you wrote

```
while (want.click=false)
```

What you wrote is an assignment not a equality check.

```
while (want.click == false)
```

That's the correct way to write it.

Comment: You're right, but there are many other problems. For instance click is not really a valid property. Thus, the loop won't stop. And also JS is asynchronous so all of his infinite interval (which should be timeout) will trigger at the same time.

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to create a functional program to fulfill what I need?

Comment: @S.Grun yup, check my answer

Comment: @S.Grun  When you type in document.getElementById("find") what do you get?

Comment: @John Krakov true, I was only thinking about the syntax problems. I didn't even check the actual code.

Comment: When I put that in by itself, nothing happens

Comment: @S.Grun then what does console.log(document.getElementById ("find")) give you?

Comment: @RoyStewart. It says: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: @S.Grun try adding a parenthesis

Comment: @RoyStewart. I'm sorry I made a mistake when I copied it.  When I put in console.log(document.getElementById ("find")). Nothing happens.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I honestly didn't realize it was this complicated

Comment: @S.Grun i don't understand why it's not displaying anything it should at least display an error

Comment: @S.Grun does your html document have an element with id="find"? If not it returns null so you won't have anything to write to the console.

Comment: omg it works!! There was an extra ! before document. I'm so happy!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your do and let keywords are capitalized. They should be lower case.

```
Let want= document.`getElementById`("bba");
```

You should use a triple equal sign here rather than an assignment operator.

it should be: `let want === document.getElementById("bba");`